# Database structure, query vs iteration

Tags: database, performance, sqlite

(Basic question that probably is a duplicate, but I don't know what to search for, so feel free to edit this question with the proper database terms)

How would one retrieve groups of rows (`family members`) from a database table based on columns (`last` and `first` names) efficiently? E.g. from this

```
last  first ...
doe   john  ...
doe   jane  ...
smith jimmy ...
smith ted   ...
smith anna  ...
```

to something like this (additional data omitted)

```
doe : [{first:john, ...}, {jane}],
smith: [{jimmy}, {ted}, {anna}]
```

Does this require retrieving the common data (last name) with `distinct`or `group by` first and then iterating with additional queries (`where last="smith"`) for each name?
I'd think that that naive approach likely is inefficient and there are better solutions.

Comment: The missing keyword probably is "hierarchy". But does this mean a query is required for each parent anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregate function:

```
SELECT last, GROUP_CONCAT(first) first
FROM tablename
GROUP BY last
```

or `JSON_GROUP_ARRAY()`:

```
SELECT last, JSON_GROUP_ARRAY(first) first
FROM tablename
GROUP BY last
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c5a27d339bb562d4b1979b881a0b8620).

Comment: `json_object_group()` seems to allow retrieval of _one_ additional column - is there a way for all columns to be returned for each group item?

Comment: Use my demo to add the new column to the table and post the link here with the expected output to clarify what you want.

Comment: Sorry, [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f09e3f22da324de22f2265d0db54cf54) with one additional column using [`json_group_object()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jgroupobject). How to aggregate more columns into the JSON object?

Comment: Solution: JSON1 functions can construct multiple elements as argument pairs `k1,v1, k2,v2, ..`, see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=21465f865f1f30988506267533306558):

Comment: This is why you should provide the expected output. json functions may return very complicated structures.